# Question about the for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In the following code why the variable 'a' refer to the index rather than the value ?

```
 for  (var a in  Values) {

     alert(Values[a]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a JavaScript Array as a normal Object with a special property named `length` (actually, it a bit more complex).  So the for..in loop behaviour is identical as for other objects:

```
var a = new Array();

a[1] = "a";
alert(a.length); // 2
alert(a[0]); // undefined

a[1000] = "b"
alert(a.length); // 1001


a[-1] = "c";
alert(a[-1]); // c

a.abc="why not";

for(var key in a)
{
  alert(key+"="+a[key]);
}
// 1=a
// 1000=b
// -1=c
// abc=why not
```

Also note that you can have gaps within your array without having to pay the memory price.

Answer (score 10):

That's by design. It's trivial to get a value in an array when you know its key, but it's much harder to get a key given a value. Values can be duplicated, so how do you know which key should be used? But a key's unique, so given a key, there's only ever one value to retrieve. So, the for loop will iterate over the keys, and it's trivial to get the associated value.

Comment: For the op: "Keys" is interchangeable with index (0..n) if the object is an Array.

Comment: @Daniel: Sort of. If you add properties to the array or `Array.prototype`, they will be included in the loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [for each...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) loop that does exactly that - enumerates only values. Coming soon to a browser near you.

```
for each(var a in Values) {
    ..
}
```

For arrays, there is a new function [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which achieves the same.

```
someArray.forEach(function(value) {
    ..
});
```